# Spring: Understanding on difference between @SessionAttributes vs @Scope('session')

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Case 1:

```
@Scope(‘Session’)
public class Employee{
  //..
}

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

  @Autowired 
  private Employee employee;
    //..
  }
}
```

Case 2:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("employee")
public class EmployeeController {

  @ModelAttribute 
  public void addEmployee(){
      //..
  }
}
```

Is Case1 and Case 2 same?

Comment: My understanding is Case 1 and case 2 does the same. 
We use @Scope(Session) to apply it to complete class. Hence I may use @Scope(‘Session’) at Controller level and make the controller and its attributes(may be POJO or primitive java variables) session scoped.  
When we use @SessionAttribute(‘model’) it limits to a particular attribute.
Please share you understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both method create a session attribute.

When using `@Scope(‘Session’)` spring determines the name, and the bean do not automatically populates the model of any controller. It is a normal bean that can be autowired. But if you want the current value (the one in current session) for autowiring in a singleton bean, you must use a scope-proxy.

When using `@SessionAttributes(‘employee’)` you declare that the model attribute `employee` will live in session. If any method of the controller needs to initialize the attribute after a submit, spring will look in session for a version of the attribute. But it cannot be autowired in another bean.

So while the 2 methods apparently gives same result : `employee` in session, they correspond to different use cases.

Comment: Thank you 
 I think you are suggesting this:
 

 
   <!-- an HTTP Session-scoped bean exposed as a proxy -->
   <bean id="employee" class="com.test.Employee" scope="session">
      <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
      <aop:scoped-proxy/>
   </bean>


Controller
public class EmployeeController 
{
   Autowired
   private Employee employee;
   
   RequestMapping("/viewEmployeeDetails")
   public ModelAndView viewEmployeeDetails()
   {
      // now just use the employee
   }  
}

Answer (score 0):

`@SessionAttributes` spring annotation declares `session attributes`.

This will typically list the names of model attributes which should be transparently stored in the session, serving as form-backing beans between subsequent requests. So it is limited to session only

While `@Scope`: Specifies the scope to use for the annotated component/bean. Its attributes can be `SINGLETON,PROTOYPE,SESSION,REQUEST`. where the default scope is `SINGLETON`