# Spring: close session info

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created a Spring MVC Project with a cart shopping bean (scope=session) and I put the Client object as:

```
@SessionAttributes(value="client")
```

If I want to eliminate all that is present in the session, this code doesn't work. Why?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String closeSession(SessionStatus status){
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";
}//closeSessione
```

1. It only removes the Client object, but if I want to eliminate also the Cart bean, how can I solve it?
2. It's better then I create the Client bean with scope = session, or is `@SessionAttributes(value="client")` also good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use @SessionAttributes, here you will find some comparison: [Spring: Understanding on difference between @SessionAttributes vs @Scope('session')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121576/spring-understanding-on-difference-between-sessionattributes-vs-scopesessio)

Try doing this to remove all the objects of the session.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String closeSession(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
    session.invalidate();  
    return "redirect:/";
}//closeSessione
```

Comment: But @SessionAttributes saves the objects into the HttpSession?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this article for further information. http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/